# Putting a tableview on a view controller which is exactly same with another tableview on a tableviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I need your help on my project.

I'm wondering if I can put a tableview on a view controller which is exactly same with a tableview on a tableviewcontroller.

I created my custom tableviewcontroller, and a tableviewcontroller object of which custom tableview controller is the mine(let's say ConA) on a storyboard and a tableview on this one works fine. Let's call this tableview Table A.

And what I want is, on the other scene of the storyboard, which is a view controller object(let's say ConB), I want to display a tableview which is exactly same with Table A. Let's call this tableview object Table B.

I think I can do it by copying tableview datasource and delegate methods of Table A  from ConA, and pasting it on ConB to which datasource and delegate of Table B is connected.

But... is there any other much simpler option that I can make Table B same with Table A?
Please help.

If anything is not clear, let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Tables A and B are supposed to be the exact same, why not use two instances of the same controller class?  If Controller B has additional functionality, you should have it inherit from Controller A and then add any additional and/or overridden methods in B's implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer refreshed me and I found what I did wrong. I haven't made Controller A a property on Contoller B. That was why I got wrong result.